# How to test a placeholder in the text field

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to verify the placeholder text present in a text field using robotframework.

[image: Username]

I have used different Selenium2Library keywords but none of them do precisely what I want.

Does anyone have an approach to getting this functionality from within my test?

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried getValue, can I check if you are using selenium or selenium 2? What is your level of python knowledge? I often find it useful to open a REPL and try running each step manually to gather information,a it may be that what you need is not in the keyword library and so you may need to write an extension.

Comment: @BiggAl .Yes I did tried GetValue and Page Should Contain keywords.I am using Selenium2 and I am ok with python coding but haven't tried any code for this thing .Please share if you have any suggestion I will try that.

Comment: In a REPL import Selenium2Library and then also open the source in your text editor of choice -you should be able to find how s2l calls selenium and in the REPL create a function that runs getAttribute as in srkgupta's example - of running this function gives you the results you are looking for reply to this comment andI'll write a full answer on how to extend s2l for your tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the command `getAttribute(input_field_locator@placeholder)`. This will return you the text you want and then you can assert on it.

Comment: This is what you would do for vanilla selenium, bit too interface this into Robotframework will take a little extra effort - see my answer for the how-to

Answer (score 0):

Once you have managed to access the functionality you are looking for from the REPL, you may find that it is not accessible via robotframework. You can expose new keywords by creating a wrapper for Selenium2Library which extends it with extra functionality - for an example see https://github.com/alistair-broomhead/scalable-robotframework-example/blob/master/TestLibraries/Selenium2Custom from a tutorial I am working on.

This example simply adds two keywords to robotframework on top of those in Selenium2Library if you instead import this class (Get Text and Get HTML, which are useful for verification):

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
class Selenium2Custom(Selenium2Library):
    """
    Custom wrapper for robotframework Selenium2Library to add extra functionality
    """
    def get_text(self, locator):
        """
        Returns the text of element identified by `locator`.

        See `introduction` for details about locating elements.
        """
        return self._get_text(locator)
    def get_html(self, id=None):
        """
        Get the current document as an XML accessor object.
        """
        from lxml import html
        src = self.get_source().encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
        page = html.fromstring(src)
        element = page.get_element_by_id(id) if id is not None else page
        return html.tostring(element)
```

As such it would be trivial to do something like this:

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
class Selenium2Custom(Selenium2Library):
    """
    Custom wrapper for robotframework Selenium2Library to add extra functionality
    """
    def get_placeholder(self, locator):
        """
        Returns the placeholder text of element identified by `locator`.
        """
        element = self._element_find(locator, True, False)
        return element.get_attribute("@placeholder")
```

Now I don't know that this will definately work for you, but for me it works like so:

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
>>> def get_placeholder(self, locator):
...     element = self._element_find(locator, True, False)
...     return element.get_attribute("placeholder")
... 
>>> Selenium2Library.get_placeholder = get_placeholder
>>> session = Selenium2Library()
>>> session.open_browser("http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page",
                         remote_url="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub")
1
>>> session.get_placeholder("search")
u'Search'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to check placeholder text and after coming here and reading the comments, I got some clue about it. Now, the tricky part is how to do this in robot framework and after doing some math, I was able to do this pretty easily. Here is my answer in 2 lines:

```
${webelement}=  Get WebElement  locator

${placeholder}=  Call Method  ${webelement}  get_attribute  placeholder
```